# Large objects in ASP.NET application cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching

So I just inherited an ASP.NET MVC app...

The app caches user permissions in the application cache, which is fine, except for the fact that it caches ***all of the permissions under a single key***. It's basically one big 50MB dictionary object with a bunch of nested dictionaries within it.

On each request the 50MB object is accessed like so:

```
public bool HasAccess(string user, string permission)
{
   var cache = (GodCache)MemoryCache.Default["GodCache"]); //I am huge
   return cache[user][permission];
}
```

What's the best case that can be made for why this <s>is</s> could be a bad idea?

Comment: refactor the code would be my best guess..

Comment: "I said so" could be the only reason you'll be able to come up with. Why do you think it is bad idea to start with?

Comment: My larger goal is to convert our application to use Redis for caching (right or wrong, it's what I want to do). Pulling a 50MB object out of Redis on each request would be prohibitive. Convincing my manager this is just bad design to begin with would strengthen my case.

Comment: The presence of the word "God" suggests anti-pattern.

Comment: Side note: "people who wrote code were complete idiots" (which how your reason will sound) is rarely good approach. I don't see why you'd need more than you've put in comment about "with new caching technology read 50M from remote cache on each request is slow" would not be enough. You may consider asking on http://http://workplace.stackexchange.com if there are better options.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think it is better to break it up into smaller objects than have 1 huge object in the cache. Under memory pressure, the cache items will be evicted. If you have one large object graph as a single item in the cache, then that whole object is going to be evicted and you have to re-construct the whole object graph again which will take a lot of time and resources.

Instead, if the cache is broken down into smaller key-value pairs, then only some of the items are going to get evicted and presumably it will take much less time and resources to re-construct that single item.

Also, if the cache is going to become an out-of-process one (like redis), there is the added overhead of seralization/deserialization of the object graph and under heavy/concurrent load it could really consume a lot of CPU cycles for a huge object.